# "Merge" data frames with different columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I need to merge/join two dataframes that have some column names in common, but also have different columns names. For example:

```
df1 = {A: hello, B: bye, C:good morning, F: nice}
df2 = {A: hola, D: buenos dias, C: adiós, G: bad}
```

So the resulting dataframe I want is like:

```
  A   |B     |C            |D           |F    |G  
----------------------------------------------------
hello |bye   |good morning |None        |nice |None
hola  |None  |adiós        |buenos dias |None |bad
```

I've been trying to merge the dataframes using the 'merge' pandas' function as follows:

```
res = pandas.merge(df1, df2, on='A')
```

But I don't get the results I want.
Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Initially, you have two data frames or two dictionaries ?

Comment: @RafaelC well, yeah, I have to dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

First, create your `pd.DataFrame` objects

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': 'hello', 'B': 'bye', 'C':'good morning', 'F': 'nice'}, index=[0])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': 'hola', "D":' buenos dias', 'C':' adiós', 'G': 'bad'}, index=[0])
```

Then, just use [`how='outer'`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer')
```

which yields

```
    A       B   C               F       D           G
0   hello   bye good morning    nice    NaN         NaN
1   hola    NaN adiós           NaN     buenos dias bad
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error:
    "type object argument after * must be an iterable, not itertools.imap"

Comment: I solved it as follows:

`res = pd.concat([df1, df2], join='outer', sort=False)`

Comment: @sooaran Your error is not a consequence of my code, because I didn't use `itertools` anywhere. But glad you could solve it

Comment: I know, I really appreciate your help!! Thanks!!